# Next.js Turbopack with MUI

Tags: next.js, material-ui, turbopack

I am using Next.js `14.0.3` pages route and Material UI (MUI).

When I try to run dev server using Turbopack.

```
"dev": "next dev --trubo",
```

I get very long error immediately after starting the dev server on all pages where MUI (icons or components) is used.

```
  18 |
> 19 | import {
     | ^^^^^^^^
> 20 |   Box,
     | ^^^^^^
> 21 |   Menu,
     | ^^^^^^
> 22 |   List,
     | ^^^^^^
> 23 |   Avatar,
     | ^^^^^^
> 24 |   AppBar,
     | ^^^^^^
> 25 |   Drawer,
     | ^^^^^^
> 26 |   Toolbar,
     | ^^^^^^
> 27 |   Divider,
     | ^^^^^^
> 28 |   MenuItem,
     | ^^^^^^
> 29 |   Typography,
     | ^^^^^^
> 30 |   IconButton,
     | ^^^^^^
> 31 |   ListItemText,
     | ^^^^^^
> 32 |   ListItemIcon,
     | ^^^^^^
> 33 |   ListItemButton,
     | ^^^^^^
> 34 | } from "@mui/material";
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  35 |
  36 | import {
  37 |   Menu as MenuIcon,
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material/ListItemIcon'
    
It was not possible to find the requested file.
    Parsed request as written in source code: module "@mui/material" with subpath "/ListItemIcon"
    Path where resolving has started: [project]/src/components/xyz/MyComponent.jsx
    Type of request: EcmaScript Modules request
    Import map: aliased to relative "./src/mui/material/ListItemIcon" inside of [project]/
    


  ⚠ /_error error - src/components/mno/HerComponent.jsx:23:0
```

I too have another project using same version of Next.js and pages route and using Tailwind CSS, Turbopack is working without any problems.

What is the problem with MUI and Turbopack?

Comment: I have all modules installed correctly and the app runs well without `--turbo`.